# Returning a value from a PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter

I have created a WordPress page that has this simple PHP code:

```
<?php
   $result = array(
       'State'   => 'Done',
       'ID'        => 1
   );

   wp_send_json( $result );
?>
```

When submitting a form in another page using Ajax(JQuery) it calls this PHP page, then in the JQuery method i try to read the returned value from the PHP page using this code:

```
$( '#contact_form' ).bootstrapValidator({
    fields: {
        // ...
    },
    submitHandler: function( formInstance ) {
        $.post( "../send-message", $("#contact_form").serialize(), function( result ) { 
            alert( result );            
        });
    }
});
```

But it actually returns the whole PHP page with its WordPress theme code used in addition to the passed parameters, as shown here:

[image]

My question is: **How can i return a PHP value from a WordPress page to a JQuery function?**

Comment: What does first page have apart from the object?

Comment: to make the AJAX answer, make it like in the page : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i return a PHP value from a WordPress page to a JQuery
>   function?

Use [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) to create an object and pass it to the JavaScript.

Comment: Your solution is right, thanks a lot. But i have problems using 'wp_localize_script' so i have asked a related question to this here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/231415/97480

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_send_json( $result );
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {

        wp_die();
}
```

**UPD**

The besat way to use ajax requests with wp is to use wp native ajax actions

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

so you need to make post request to admin-ajax.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-js', PATH_TO_JS . '/script.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'frontend-js',
            'wpUser',
            [
                'ajaxUrl'        => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            ] );

$.post( wpUser.ajaxUrl, { action: 'my_action' } );
```

Comment: Just dumping some code is not an answer. Please explain why your code works for what OP wants.

Comment: @cjbj, the request to the php page will return the whole page with loaded wp, so we need to stop after sending necessary data